# How to convert HashMap with key/value label property

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have HashMap like `Map<CategoryEnum, List<GroupEnum>>`, it represent category wise list of group enum. We need a represent like

```
{
{
"category":"Category Enum1",
"groups":["g1","g2"]
},
{
"category":"Category Enum2",
"groups":["g1","g2"]
}
}
```

I have created a POJO class like below and manually map the POJO and return list of CategoryGroup.

```
    Class CategroyGroup{
    private Category category;
    private List<Group> groups;
//other code

    }
```

I could not found a way to generate this kind of JSON without introduce new POJO class.

Comment: ur target json is not a valid json. I don't think there exists a library can parse it.

Comment: we need to return json for enum. its not about valid or invalid. we need fix label for key / value to identify on UI side

Comment: @iMBMT PWC means the JSON should be `["g1","g2"]` not `{"g1","g2"}`.

Comment: @kennytm yes it was typo mistake. corrected. thanks at PWC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `CategoryEnum` and `GroupEnum` have getValue methods.

Assuming this is the output you are looking for:

```
[{
    "category":"Category Enum1",
    "groups":["g1","g2"]
}, {
    "category":"Category Enum2",
    "groups":["g1","g2"]
}]

public List<CategoryGroup> getCategories(Map<CategoryEnum, List<GroupEnum>> map) {
    List<CategoryGroup> categories = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Map.Entry<CategoryEnum, List<GroupEnum>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        CategoryGroup group = new CategoryGroup();
        group.setCategory(entry.getKey().getValue());
        group.setGroup(getGroupList(entry.getValue()));
    }
    return categories;
}

private List<Group> getGroups(List<GroupEnum> list) {
    List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();
    for (GroupEnum groupEnum : list) {
        groups.add(groupEnum.getValue());
    }
    return groups;
}
```

Comment: No, I don't need to create Pojo to convet map to such json structure. I am looking for any jackson or library which will allowed us to add label with key and value.

Comment: `Map<CategoryEnum, List<GroupEnum>>` will appear is JSON as:
{
categoryEnum1: {
 groups: ["g1", "g2"]
},
categoryEnum2: {
 groups: ["g1", "g2]
}
}

They are completely different representation and is very specific. You'll have to do it yourself.